# google scholar pubblication

Tags: php, file-get-contents, google-scholar

I created a php script to retrieve the results from google scholar.

```
function getUserScholarPage($authorId){
$userUrl = "http://scholar.google.it/citations?hl=it&user=" . $authorId . "&view_op=list_works&pagesize=10000";
$html = file_get_html($userUrl);
$rows = $html->find('#gsc_a_b tr[class="gsc_a_tr"]');

return $rows;
```

}

```
function getUserScholarBibliography( $rows ){
    $publications = array();


foreach( $rows as $row ){
    $citations = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $row->find('td[class="gsc_a_c"] a', 0)->plaintext) != '' ? trim($row->find('td[class="gsc_a_c"] a', 0)->plaintext) : 0;

    $year = ($row->find('td[class="gsc_a_y"]', 0)->plaintext) ? trim($row->find('td[class="gsc_a_y"]', 0)->plaintext) : 0;
    $url  = getRealPaperURL('http://scholar.google.it' . $row->find('a[class="gsc_a_at"]',0)->href);
    $type = 'ARTICLE';
    $title = trim($row->find('a[class="gsc_a_at"]',0)->innertext);

    $publications[] = array(
        'type'    => $type,
        'title'   => $title,
        'authors' => trim($row->find('div[class="gs_gray"]',0)->innertext),
        'journal' => trim(preg_replace("'<span[^>]*?>.*?</span>'si", '', $row->find('div[class="gs_gray"]',1)->innertext)),
        'citations' => $citations,
        'year'      => $year,
        'url'       => $url,
        'unique_identifier' => hash('md5', $year . $url . $title)
    );
}

return $publications;
```

}

But I have a problem when calling the query.
I get an error:

Warning:  file_get_contents(http://scholar.google.it/citations?hl=it&user=XXXXXXX&view_op=list_works&pagesize=10000): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
 in /var/www/html/scholar/simple_html_dom.php on line 78

-simple_html_dom.php on line 78

https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/blob/master/simple_html_dom.php

Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/scholar/scholar-biblio-loader.php on line 21

-scholar-biblio-loader.php on line 21

```
$rows = $html->find('#gsc_a_b tr[class="gsc_a_tr"]');
```

if I run the script in localhost works. 
If I run the script on my server gives me the error

google blocks the call? what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: [503](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html) means the service is unavailable. Perhaps Google is not eager to respond to servers?